# Shifting between user controls in WPF and memory waste

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I wanted to ask the correct way to handle changing between user controls in my user interface. My main window exchanges user controls in its content part of the grid. As I was shifting between them testing, I couldn't help to notice that it using more and more memory. As this application will see heavy use in the future, I wanted to know how to properly dispose of the user controls that are no longer in use. I was simply loading the new controls like this.

```
StackPanelContent.Children.Clear();

StackPanelContent.Children.Add(new CataloeAlumns());
```

But now I realize that I need to release the one used previously, but have no clear idea of how. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell WPF makes this the frameworks problem and doesn't provide any mechanism to do it yourself.

Comment: unused controls will be garbage collected

Comment: Yes, I won't really worry much about disposing the controls

Comment: `I wanted to ask the correct way to handle changing between user controls in my user interface.` - Learn MVVM. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code.